# True or false validation to check whether web compiled user input is equal to a locally stored value

Tags: python

My question title does not succinctly explain my objective. Let me improve on that.
I am mildly familiar with extending an IDE functionality in a web application. Lets assume that in I somehow manage to store a predetermined value, the correct output of a certain formula; a sorted list of x int values -[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] . It can be sorted using any sorting algorithm. An example shell_sort algo:

```
def shell_sort(list):
    gap = len(list) // 2

    while gap > 0:
        for i in range(gap, len(list)):
            temp = list[i]
            j = i
            while j >= gap and list[j-gap] > temp:
                list[j] = list[j-gap]
                j = j - gap

            list[j] = temp
        gap = gap // 2

list = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
shell_sort(list)
print(list)
```

The output of the above function should be: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].

Please note that I somehow have figured a way to store the correct output of the algorithm. False or True, for now. How can, when a user using a web-ide integrated platform solving for example the algorithm above, be able to programmatically determine the correctness of the users output against one stored locally?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've read this question 3 times and I'm still not sure what you're asking.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @michjnich, I'm the one who should be sorry. For example, take a webiste like AlgoExpert

Comment: After a user submits their code, there is a way to tell whether a users output is correct, and therefore testcases pass. Otherwise not.

Comment: Not familiar with that one, but I've used others. Usually they will have a whole load of test cases defined (some of which the user can see, some not), and "correct" means passing them all.

Comment: Thanks @michjnich. I wanted to ask for a few clarifications, but your last comment opened another event of angle/s I haven't considered.

Comment: Removing unrelated tags and adding `python`